# How to use "fromNow" materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I dont have much experience with JS and I am not about to figure out how "fromNow" works in materialize CSS. could you please help me out!
I dont understand how to use this!

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

[image]

code:
JS(atleast what I could do):

```
$('#start_time').timepicker({
  onSelect: function(time, min) {
    console.log(time)
    console.log(min)
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" id="start_time" name="start_time" class="timepicker Vwhite-text" placeholder="Start Time*"><!--onchange="changeendtime()-->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="text" id="end_time" name="end_time" class="timepicker Vwhite-text" placeholder="End Time*">
      </div>
    </div>
```

goal:I am trying to add 30 min to the start time and set that value to the end time...

Comment: I don't use materialize but seems like just what is written, `fromNow`: how much millisecond from now you need into `select` time

Comment: Do you even need this? It's not necessary to understand every single aspect of a tool like this in order to use it successfully. Also, why not experiment with a bunch of different values and see what you can find out?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i am using select with this :), please look at my other comment for more details :))

Comment: @ChrisG i wanted to add 30 min to the time set, thats why i wanted to use this thing,m since the input is "text" and not time it is much harder to do that using JS, thats why i needed this. could you help me with that?

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried to the question, and a description of how it fails? Did you set the `fromNow` value to `30 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: @ChrisG I will add that :) but please keep in mind that I dont know anything about frontend, so yea, please help me through that, I dont know how to set that value let alone add it!

Comment: Sounds like all you need is: https://jsfiddle.net/vjmnbz1a/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234329/discussion-between-vardhan-mahajan-and-chris-g).